# ListView onItemClickListener or Inner view click listener?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, onitemclicklistener

Which one of the two approaches is better regarding the performance and maintainance:

1. Implementing `listView.setOnItemClickListener()`
2. Adding `click listener` to `convertView` or view object in `getView()`
   method.

Also does adding click listener in getView method of adapter violates Single Responsibility Principle?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: not on `getView` method, but in `ViewHolder` class - yes.

Comment: @SergeyShustikov, I am still not clear....using ViewHolders we can have click listeners on the row elements but applying click listener on the layout's main parent (may be Linear or Relative) in ViewHolder is a better approach or implementation of  listView.setOnItemClickListener() is better?
Also can you please provide more info on your answer as "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation. With a simple list the first approach is recommended. If you have a custom adapter with focusable views I recommend the second approach.

Respeonsibilty is not related to adding of the click listener but to what the click listener does. If it performs some business logic (with a symptom of change) inside the adapter it violates SRP.